# Fail to retrieve the value from gsm sim 900A by using AT Command to PHP script

Tags: gsm

I am currently trying to establish a connection between my gsm sim900A to one of my test server. The connection seems pretty good so far, though I'm a little bit confused why there are **no values retrieved** by my php file. Even so, the insert query works although it insert empty value into the database. So my question is how to retrieve it properly? I already change the method in php script to POST, both of it doesn't return any good signs.

Arduino Code:

```
void postData()
{
  sim900a.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  sim900a.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  sim900a.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"test.my/demo/writedata.php\"");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  sim900a.println("AT+HTTPDATA=12,10000");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  sim900a.println("strBoton=999");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  sim900a.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  sim900a.println("AT+HTTPREAD");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  sim900a.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$servername = "test.my";
$username = "****";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$Boton = $_GET["strBoton"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('$Boton')";   

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Output:

```
AT+HTTPINIT
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","test.my/demo/writedata.php"
OK

AT+HTTPDATA=12,10000
DOWNLOAD
OK

AT+HTTPACTION=1
OK

AT+HTTPREAD
OK

AT+HTTPTERM
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed

AT+SAPBR=0,1
OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but, in this [tutorial](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM900/SIM900_HTTPS%20AT%20Command%20Set_V1%2000.pdf) at page 8, it does almost the same code pattern like yours. You might want to check it. Sorry but I don't know PHP, I can't help you with it.

But I am confused with AT+HTTPACTION, since AT+HTTPACTION=0 is the read and AT+HTTPACTION=1 is the post. Check the tutorial and optimize your commands.

Also check [this](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/athttpterm-terminate-the-http-session/) one. It writes WAIT=6 after AT+HTTPREAD before terminating it.

Comment: my references are both the link that u provide in the first paragraph and this one, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231224/posting-to-php-server-using-sim900-gprs-with-at-commands . I am still learning how to arduino by the way so i'm having a hard time swallowing the flow of the codes.

Comment: i will try to modify the codes and differentiate between AT+HTTPACTION=0 and 1 for now, as for the WAIT=6, I believe that is the delay time after the execution. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I will check the link you send. I will command on it if anything necessary. Thanks for the link by the way.

Comment: I'll change it to AT+HTTPACTION=0 and remove certain lines of codes and it works! Thank you sir. :)

Comment: Your welcome, always happy to help a fellow ;-)